# run django multiple application on different ports

Tags: django, gunicorn, cloud-foundry

How to run multiple apps in different port in django? i am using gunicorn. i want to run the multiple applications on same domain.

my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn DCMS_API.wsgi:application
```

i have app1 and app2 in DCMS_API.

How do i host the multiple applications on same domain name as i am new to django, i am facing issue while hosting the application. my django project is uploaded with different domain names apps name getting added in the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i did a little research. if i add single app on manifest.yml, that application name gets added in the domain name, But rest of the apps need not to be added. You can access it by ****.com/app2.